# Why is just one of my spring entities taking over 5 seconds to query

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a spring backend application that has over 30 entities but for some reason the user object takes forever to do anything. Just retrieving all users (which is only like 15) takes 6 seconds!! On top of this just calling

```java
User user = new User();
```

Takes over 100ms which makes no sense to me. I have no idea what could be causing this issue. Below is the user model and some of the sql that is generated from querying for all users.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbluser")
@Immutable
public class User {

    private int userId;
    private String password;
    private String company;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String userName;
    private String phone;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String country;
    private String postal;
    private Set<UserRole> roles;
    private Integer isActive;
    private String userFolder;

    public User(){
        this("new", "PASSWORD", "new", "new", "",  1, "", "", "", "", "", "");
    }

    public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName){
        this(userName, password, firstName, lastName, "", 1, "", "", "", "", "", "");
    }

    public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, Integer isActive){
        this(userName, password, firstName, lastName, "",  isActive, "", "", "", "", "", "");
    }

    public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Integer isActive,
         String company, String phone, String address1, String address2, String country, String postal
         ){
        this.setUserName(userName);
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password));
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setIsActive(isActive);
        this.setCompany(company);
        this.setPhone(phone);
        this.setAddress1(address1);
        this.setAddress2(address2);
        this.setCountry(country);
        this.setPostal(postal);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "username")
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", updatable = false)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "company")
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "phone")
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Column(name = "address1")
    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    @Column(name = "address2")
    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    @Column(name = "country")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Column(name = "postal")
    public String getPostal() {
        return postal;
    }

    public void setPostal(String postal) {
        this.postal = postal;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_folder")
    public String getUserFolder() {
        return userFolder;
    }

    public void setUserFolder(String userFolder) {
        this.userFolder = userFolder;
    }

    @Column(name = "isactive")
    public Integer getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Integer isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "tbluserrolemap", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    public Set<UserRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<UserRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }



}
```

And here is the sql that is generated as well as some joins for the user roles. It should be eagerly loaded but even still there aren't that many users so that shouldn't be making much of a difference.

```js
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.userId as userId1_63_,
        user0_.address1 as address2_63_,
        user0_.address2 as address3_63_,
        user0_.company as company4_63_,
        user0_.country as country5_63_,
        user0_.email as email6_63_,
        user0_.firstname as firstnam7_63_,
        user0_.isActive as isActive8_63_,
        user0_.lastname as lastname9_63_,
        user0_.password as passwor10_63_,
        user0_.phone as phone11_63_,
        user0_.postal as postal12_63_,
        user0_.user_folder as user_fo13_63_,
        user0_.username as usernam14_63_ 
    from
        tbluser user0_
Hibernate: 
select
    roles0_.user_id as user_id1_64_0_,
    roles0_.role_id as role_id2_64_0_,
    userrole1_.role_id as role_id1_3_1_,
    userrole1_.name as name2_3_1_ 
from
    tbluserrolemap roles0_ 
inner join
    tbluserroles userrole1_ 
        on roles0_.role_id=userrole1_.role_id 
where
    roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: 
select
    roles0_.user_id as user_id1_64_0_,
    roles0_.role_id as role_id2_64_0_,
    userrole1_.role_id as role_id1_3_1_,
    userrole1_.name as name2_3_1_ 
from
    tbluserrolemap roles0_ 
inner join
    tbluserroles userrole1_ 
        on roles0_.role_id=userrole1_.role_id 
where
    roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: 
select
    roles0_.user_id as user_id1_64_0_,
    roles0_.role_id as role_id2_64_0_,
    userrole1_.role_id as role_id1_3_1_,
    userrole1_.name as name2_3_1_ 
from
    tbluserrolemap roles0_ 
inner join
    tbluserroles userrole1_ 
        on roles0_.role_id=userrole1_.role_id 
where
    roles0_.user_id=?
```

```js
CREATE TABLE `tbluser` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isactive` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_folder` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
)

CREATE TABLE `tbluserrolemap` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_roleid_idx` (`role_id`),
  KEY `fk_userid_idx` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_roleid` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `tbluserroles` (`role_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_userid` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tbluser` (`userId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE `tbluserroles` (
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`)
)
```

Comment: Show the full query, `SHOW EXPLAIN {query}` results. Show `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for each table. You haven't got the right indexes.

Comment: `FetchType.EAGER` - change to LAZY?

Comment: Also `user_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,` - why null on FK?

Comment: @danblack is the updated info what you are referring too. The full query is very long but follows on with the same thing that I added.

Comment: @ScaryWombat because I did that like a year ago and obviously wasn't thinking straight haha. But I actually want it to be EAGER. There aren't very many users so the overhead isn't something that I am worried about (for the moment).

Comment: Does this take a long time when using a mysql client?

Comment: @danblack Also the big pause is right after the first select statement. The statements after run like clockwork.

Comment: @ScaryWombat No when using mysql client it is instant. This leads me to believe it is a spring issue. I am using spring data so in this case its just a repository that extends Repository and the function call is just findAll(). Also no other entity has this issue.

Comment: Are you sure it is not opening new connections?  Are you using a DBCP?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes I am using the BasicDataSource from dbcp2.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have fixed it. It really didn't like me overriding the empty constructor for an entity. Removed that and everything is lightning fast. Not sure why exactly but whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it was that I was overriding the empty constructor for the user entity. Spring really doesn't like this apparently. Removed that and the call executed in under 10 milliseconds.